# LLVM IR: Branch instruction with variable BasicBlock target?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

> Does LLVM support for branch instructions with a variable BasicBlock target?

More specifically, suppose I convert all unconditional `br` instructions into function calls to some function `f`. Is it then possible to provide the target label as an argument to `f`, and then use this label in an unconditional branch within `f`?

Or is the only solution to make a `switch` in `f`, map all BB's to unique ID's, and then call `f` with the ID corresponding to the target BB?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, non-local indirect branches to labels aren't possible.

http://blog.llvm.org/2010/01/address-of-label-and-indirect-branches.html?m=1

Comment: Are you sure? From what I can see, the author chooses not to discuss that topic, or?